# Google sheet making copies on its own

Tags: google-sheets

I made a copy of a google sheet couple of month then suddenly I found that it duplicates 10-20 times every day on its own. No one has this account but myself, and I have no automation tools linked to this sheet. Also this sheet was taken from a trusted source. I tried deleting them from google sheets and google drive but they duplicate back again even after clearing the trash.

I tried deleting all instances from google sheets and google drive and empty the trash but it still comes back